# cannot execute jax code jax.random.PRNGKey(0)

Tags: jax

I had a problem with jax where I would get stuck executing **jax.random.PRNGKey(0)**. Previously the jax code could successfully execute until I killed some background processes and then the problem occurred.

```
def main():
    jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
```

I thought maybe some defunct process caused this so I had checked the background process but didn't find any problem.
[process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znCzl.png)

Comment: Provide a stack trace, please. The error message and whatever you think could help us help you.

Comment: This probably means that the jaxlib package you have installed is misconfigured for your system. It will be difficult to help without more information: could you edit your question and paste the full traceback you're seeing, as well as system information and which jax/jaxlib versions you have installed?